# Record between a date range spanning across 2 columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get the record between a date range spanning across 2 columns.

[image: between statusEnteredDate and newDate in the image(Please click here)]

As of now I have tried below code but that does not seems to be taking the newDate column in the consideration.

I want that row also in the consideration which has value in `newColumn`

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(`status_data`.`statusEnteredDate`, `status_data`.`newDate`) as twinData,
       count(*) as MY_COUNT
FROM `status_data`
WHERE (`status_data`.`statusEnteredDate` BETWEEN '2019/02/24 10:00' AND '2019/03/01 10:00'
       OR `status_data`.`newDate` BETWEEN 'null' AND '2019/02/27 10:00')
GROUP By `recordUniqueID`
ORDER by `id` ASC
```

I need to retain the `GROUP By` here as I want the count of repeated row as well.

Also is there any way I can apply the logic in the same SQL query on `COALESCE`? Because in this way I am able to merge the two columns together. Something like below:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(`status_data`.`statusEnteredDate`, `status_data`.`newDate`) as twinData,
       count(*) as MY_COUNT
FROM `status_data`
WHERE (`twinData` BETWEEN '2019/02/24 10:00' AND '2019/02/27 10:00')
GROUP By `recordUniqueID`
ORDER by `id` ASC
```

Above code is not giving me the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result? Please share the full table structure, sample data, and the expected output

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not allowed to embed the image yet although you can click on the link to view the image. The desired result is expected to fetch all the rows falling between the 2 dates and grouping them by the recordUniqueID column.

Comment: You should not embed any image. Share such information in text form, such that others can work with it

Comment: Sure, let me try, We have dates across 2 columns(statusEnteredDate and newDate). We have a date range(2 dates) in the PHP form. I am supposed to fetch all the rows which has dates between those 2 dates from the above listed 2 columns.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing text formatted example data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes around the `null`, so it is interpreted as zero. And you are not handling `NULL` comparisons correctly.  I think you want:

```
select . . .
from status_data sd
where (sd.statusEnteredDate >= '2019-02-24 10:00' and
       sd.statusEnteredDate < '2019-03-01 10:00'
      ) and
      (sd.newDate is null or
       sd.newDate < '2019-02027 10:00'
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is still not working. I am sorry if I am not clear in presenting my question. What actually I want is like  I have 2 dates say '2019-02-27 05:03:00' and '2019-03-01 10:00:00'. I want a query something like below:

$sql = "select * from status_data" where statusEnteredDate + newDate between '2019-02-27 05:03:00' and '2019-03-01 10:00:00'";

How do I achieve this? Thanks once again for your help on this.